# How do i use javascript judged the input box filled by the scanner or use keyboard?

Tags: javascript

I have an input box,and I want to use JavaScript judged the input box filled by the scanner or keyboard!

Just like this

```
if(by scanner){
    //do things
 }else if(by keyboard){
    //do other things
 }
```

Comment: What do you mean by **by the scanner** ?

Comment: Scanner scann the barcode and the number filled the input box

Comment: Where is all the stuff that handle the scanner ? What have you tried ?

Comment: It's ERP Software systems. .In the beginning i added keydown and keyup event